# Tracking multiple java applications resources allocation

Tags: java, memory, jvm, process-monitoring

Can you suggest me a tool for monitoring multiple java processes
running on a Windows 7 machine.

More specifically I have like 10 similar applications running with default JVM settings.
I need information for the memory allocation over time, to identify possible memory leaks and to adjust more resources somewhere if needed.

Some free tools with logs and graphs will be perfect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about the standard JVM [JVisualVM](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/tools/share/jvisualvm.html) or [VisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/)

Comment: Or for JRocked JRocket Mission Control

Comment: JVisualVM looks promising will give it a try.